Unzip Folder - Power BI
I have zipped folder include 5 .xlsx files.
Trying to unzip the folder and use the files in Power BI, I received the following error.

As you can see in the above image, the files are Excel files but the error seems that do not regocnize the correct files type.
Any help will be appreciated.
